# Configuration of a Dell managed switch clashes with my network understanding

Tags: switch, osi, management, dell

I got the opportunity to play around with a Dell managed switch from the 2000 series with OS10. I tried to configure a management IP adress 10.10.12.141 (/24) according to the manual but somehow failed miserably, so I have a few questions (Dell OS10 commands as far as I can remember).

First, configuring it via DHCP works as expected, so I know the network is working and DHCP is served. I can SSH into the device/can ping other devices from the device:

```
configure
interface mgmt 1/1/1
ip address dhcp
no shutdown
copy running-config startup-config
```

But as soon as I switch to a static IP I can't reach the managed switch nor can I ping other systems from the switch:

```
configure
interface mgmt 1/1/1
no ip address dhcp
ip address 10.10.12.141/24
no shutdown
copy running-config startup-config
```

Now I am a bit confused because it looks like I make a fundamental mistake (**Question 1**: What mistake). From what I know and can remember about the OSI layer 2 and 3 a ping in a local network doesn't require a gateway nor a configured management route. The source devices takes the target IP/own IP + subnet and checks if the target address is within the network. If so the ARP table is checked to lookup a potential MAC adress for the target IP adress (If not, an ARP request is sent through the network). Then the frame is created and sent (**Question 2**: Is this correct).

In addition as **question 3**: How to I configure a potential gateway `10.10.12.254` (Syntax wise) for the network, so I can leave the current network (Assuming my understanding from question 2 is correct).

Comment: The management interface of a switch is like a host on the network, so, yes, it does require a configured gateway to be able to send traffic to a different network. The management interface does not take part in the switching, which does not require a gateway to switch, but the management of the switch does require a gateway.

Comment: Not sure about Dell, but try `ip route`.